# Cannot login to the application using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

How to overcome Azure AD Conditional Access sign-in when we tried to access using selenium. When login manually in the application (Which uses SSO login using Azure AD) I can able to login but when i tried the same using selenium(Python Robot framework). i'm getting the below error.[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hnPT.png)

"Message: AADSTS165000: Invalid Request: The request did not include the required tokens for the user context."

i tried the below code to overcome the issue
open browser    ${url}      ${browser}      options=add_argument("--incognito");add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking"); add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors"); add_argument("--disable-application-cache"); add_argument("--no-sandbox"); add_argument("--enable-logging"); add_argument("--disable-web-security"); add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content"); add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); add_argument("--disable-gpu"); add_argument("--disable-webgl"); add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]); add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.